# How to load view in ViewController with code?

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, initialization

I want to test a function of a ViewController that changes a label.text.
At first I tried this:

```
ViewController* controller = [[ViewControlleralloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone"bundle:nil];
[controller pressed];
NSLog(@"%@",controller.label.text);
```

the function pressed is below:

```
-(void)pressed{
self.label.text = @"hello";
}
```

however, the result is NULL.
Later I changed code as followed:

```
AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplicationsharedApplication] delegate];
ViewController* controller = [[ViewControlleralloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone"bundle:nil];
delegate.window.rootViewController = controller;
[controller pressed];
NSLog(@"%@",controller.label.text);
```

I think this code

```
delegate.window.rootViewController = controller;
```

can load the controller's view so that the label's text can be changed.But I don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct.

A view isn't loaded until it is needed. Simply creating a view controller doesn't trigger view loading but assigning the window's root view controller requires it to be set up for display and therefore instantiates and links all the nib objects.

Any reference to the view would also have caused it to load, even something like:

```
ViewController* controller = [[ViewControlleralloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone"bundle:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", controller.view);
```